# why thinks cakephp3 that its running under cli

Tags: apache, cakephp, command-line-interface, error-log

On every view in my cakephp3-app cake tries to write to cli-error.log. Why? I have no idea how to debug this...

```
Warning: file_put_contents(/home/matthias/www/bserp.localhost/logs/cli-error.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/matthias/www/bserp.localhost/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Log/Engine/FileLog.php on line 134 


//debug(array('php_sapi_name' => php_sapi_name()));
[
    'php_sapi_name' => 'apache2handler'
]
```

Comment: Best bet is to make that file writable and see what it's saying.

Comment: chown -R www-data logs/, chmod -R 777 logs/
This was of course the first thing I did. Sorry, forgot to mention this.

Comment: I am not the only one with this problem: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/6729

Comment: The irc channel-logs to the issue above told me, that chmod 755 or 775 solves the problem. Does not work for me.

Comment: I'd start with checking if, and where exactly the `Log.error.file` config is being set to `cli-error` (normally this happens in `bootstrap_cli.php`).

Comment: Adding a debug() function to the bootstrap_cli.php file is not executed.

Comment: Ok, and now continue to check _if_, and _where_ the config value is being changed. Knowing that `bootstrap_cli` isn't loaded just rules out one possible cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this was the most stupid error ever happend to me. I accidentay copy/pasted the warning in plain text into the config/route.php file of an plugin.

So apache didn't drop this warning but just printed text in the file.

sorry for beeing an idiot :)

Comment: lol it's always the stupid mistakes that take a long time to discover